# .htaccess url rewrite in Yii2

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, yii2

I am newbie. I am trying to rewrite all .css file to a PHP file by using .htaccess:

I want to when I call http://yii2web/admin/css/site.css it will rewrite to http://yii2web/admin/index.php/optioncss

Here are my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
```

## rewrite all .css file to controller optioncss here

```
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ admin/index.php/optioncss [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php [L]
```

but it does not work for me. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: But `http://yii2web/admin/index.php/optioncss` is an url that has to be rewritten as well?

Comment: @Jerodev when I call url http://yii2web/admin/index.php/optioncss via browser it work well.

Comment: Do you use pretty urls in yii?

Comment: Yes. also please be noted that is Yii2. it work fine for me in yii1. I also take a simple test: RewriteRule ^admin/abc/site.abc$ backend/web/index.php/test [L] when I call http://yii2web/admin/abc/site.abc it does not access to test controller. :(

Comment: Why don't you just add an [url rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules) for these stylesheets? You don't have to edit the htaccess for this.